# Models of a theory in an elementary topos.

Tags: category-theory, model-theory, topos-theory

This is a very short question.

Any consistent first order theory has a model in Set.
Is it true that any consistent first order theory has a model in an elementary topos?

Comment: Do you mean to ask "is there a model of every coherent theory in every elementary topos", or are you asking if the notion of "model in an elementary topos" makes sense in the first place?

Comment: I am meaning the notion at page 530 in Sheaves in Geometry and Logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is no, FinSet has no Models for Peano Numbers.